# Sqlite Rails foreign key : where in rails can i write something like FOREIGN KEY(User_id) REFERENCES User(id)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, foreign-keys

I have 2 modules in my Rails app, School and Students, obviously, School has many students and Student belongs to School.

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :students

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base  
    belongs_to :school
```

i used to understand that this means that rails will search for a column named school_id in the Student table which is a foreign key for the school..

the thing is if i entered a new student with id 6 for example and their is no school with this id, rails will create the entry without any errors or problem !!

is there is a certain place where i should declare that `FOREIGN KEY(school_id) REFERENCES School(id)`

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no necessary to mention foreign key if you want you write

```
has_many :students, :foreign_key => 'school_id'
```

Comment: same result, my problem is , if i entered in the console `Student.create(name:'gamal', school_id:'44')` and there is no school with `id: 44` !!

Comment: try school = School.create(:name => "test") and Student.create(:school_id => school.id) or school.students << Student.new